# Why does Docker prevent attaching a container to both host and user defined bridge network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Why is it that Docker prohibits attaching a container to both the host and user defined bridge network?

Secondly, for deployments that require disabling IP forwarding on the host machine does docker recommend deploying docker containers with host networking only, since based on what i understand that seems to be the only option left.

Any insights on the above two?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that Docker prohibits attaching a container to both the host and user defined bridge network?

Because there's no way to "attach" networks when a container is running in the host network namespace.

Docker attaches networks by adding virtual interfaces to a container's isolated network namespace. When running in the global network namespace, there's no sane way to do this: any new interfaces wouldn't be restricted to the container, and would potentially disrupt host networking.

> Secondly, for deployments that require disabling IP forwarding on the host machine does docker recommend deploying docker containers with host networking only, since based on what i understand that seems to be the only option left.

That's probably the only easy option.

You could run a proxy service on the host that would expose services in Docker containers. You could potentially even automate that by monitoring the Docker for events and getting information about published ports. Otherwise you would need to manually implement the appropriate configuration.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Could you please help me understand better your second answer, specifically,"You could run a proxy service on the host that would expose services in Docker containers", do you mean this is another option aside from host networking? If so, please clarify more on this in terms of what network the containers run on and what the proxy would run on & how it could expose the services..

Comment: The containers would just run on the normal docker networks. Instead of ip forwarding and nat, you would run proxy software on the host (nginx/traefik/whatever) that would redirect incoming traffic to host ports to the services in your docker containers.

Comment: Thanks again @larsks, may be i need to read more, do you mean for example that my services in docker containers could run on say a user-defined bridge network and my proxy on the host would still be able to redirect & proxy even with IP forwarding disabled?

Comment: Yes, your docker containers have ip addresses that are reachable from your host. So a proxy running on your host can connect outside connections with those containers. I'm not sure what you mean by "redirect and proxy"; whichever proxy software you choose would do what it normally does and act like a proxy. This would probably require manual setup on your part (or perhaps a docker-aware proxy, like Traefik). Probably easiest to just try setting it up and see what you get.

Comment: Cool...thank you so much for the clarification & the time! That clears up my doubts. I am now going to try & play around. On the "redirect/proxy.." part, never mind..just typed that way..also another thanks for introducing Traefik to me..:-).

Comment: The thing is i have Kafka also which needs to be reachable from external entities that publish telemetry & other messages that need to be consumed & ingested by the services...need to see how that will work in this setup without ip forwarding..